# CakePHP: Overwrite existing duplicate data

Tags: cakephp, duplicates, overwrite

How can I get Cake to use REPLACE INTO instead of INSERT INTO? I have an action that saves data into the database but I don't want to have duplicate entries. The primary keys (id) are unique, if the value already exists I don't want it to be entered as a new row.

The data being saved is also generated dynamically, so exiting with an error would not be appropriate.

EDIT
Initally the data I'm saving is in a single large array

```
$data = Array([0] => 'value1', [1] => 'value2', [2] => 'value3') etc
```

I'm trying to loop through this array, saving each value as a new record

```
foreach ($data as $value) { 
    $save_data['Model'] = array('field' => $value);
}
Classregistry::init('Model')->saveAll($save_data);
```

I'm using Classregistry because I am saving the data to a different model. Currently this code craps out when trying to insert a duplicate record because 'field' is a unique index. Before using CakePHP I just used the REPLACE INTO syntax without problems. I'd like to achieve something similar in Cake.

The only workaround I have at the moment is to allow duplicates to be entered but only display unique rows by grouping them.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the primary key in your data:

```
// create a new record
$this->Model->create();
$this->Model->save(array(
  'Model' => array(
    'name' => 'new record'
  )
));

// update it
$this->Model->save(array(
  'Model' => array(
    'id' => $id,
    'name' => 'updated record'
  )
));
```

In your edit views, simply put:

```
echo $this->Form->input('id'); // or your custom PK field
```

Comment: It's worth noting there are other ways of doing this, such as setting the `id` param on the model before saving.

Comment: I'm not sure I was being clear. I have a large array of data of unknown size. I'd like to loop the array and save each entry as a new record but avoid inserting duplicates.

Comment: The same idea applies. How do you know if it's unique? Do you have the id in the large array? If so, use that. Otherwise you need to loop and look up by some other unique field. You may need to rephrase your question and include a snippet of possible array values.

Answer (score 0):

In cakephp 3.0 there is no $this->Model->create(); it will return you undefined error.

we can do it by passing the data similar like below

```html
foreach($sizeCategories as $sizeData){
 
 $iteamData['Item_Code']  = 'abc-'.$sizeData->sizes_id;
 $iteamData['Item_Desc']  = '';
 $iteamData['Article_ID'] = 0;
 $iteamData['ColorId']  = $colorData;
 $iteamData['CreatedBy']  = $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.id');
 $iteamData['CreatedDate']  = Time::now();
 $iteamData['UpdateDate']   = Time::now();
 $iteamData['Status']    = '1';
 
 // Generaly we used $this->ItemMaster->patchEntity($itemMaster, $iteamData); that will update the data and overwrite the same entry again & again we should use the $this->ItemMaster->newEntity($iteamData); 
 // save data in loop 
 $itemMaster = $itemMaster = $this->ItemMaster->newEntity($iteamData);   
 
 if ($this->ItemMaster->save($itemMaster)) {
  $this->Flash->success(__('The products has been generated.'));
 }else{
  $this->Flash->error(__('The products could not be generate. Please, try again.'));
 }
}
```